# How to match space in MarkLogic using CTS functions?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I need to search those elements who have space `" "` in their attributes.

For example:

```
<unit href="http:xxxx/unit/2 ">
```

Suppose above code have space in the last for href attribute.

I have done this using `FLOWER` query. But I need this to be done using CTS functions. Please suggest.

For `FLOWER` query I have tried this:

```
let $x := (
  for $d in doc()
  order by $d//id
  return            
   for $attribute in data($d//@href)
   return                
   if (fn:contains($attribute," ")) then 
     <td>{(concat( "id = " , $d//id) ,",  data =", $attribute)}</td> 
   else ()
)
return <tr>{$x}</tr>
```

This is working fine.

For `CTS` I have tried

```
let $query := 
  cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("methodology"), 
                                    xs:QName("href"), 
                                    xs:string(" "),
                                    "wildcarded")                  
let $search := cts:search(doc(), $query)    
return fn:count($search)
```

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya I have updated the question.

Comment: can you please clean up your examples?  you start with a sample element called unit. Then you switch to an element called ID in the FLWOR statement and then show an example using an element called methodology.  I was trying to build out some sample data to test based on the first, then started to refactor it instead, please give a full example document and base your code on that document, please

Answer (score 2):

Your query is looking for " " to be the entirety of the value of the attribute. If you want to look for attributes that contain a space, then you need to use wildcards. However, since there is no indexing of whitespace except for exact value queries (which are by definition not wildcarded), you are not going to get a lot of index support for that query, so you'll need to run this as a filtered search (which you have in your code above) with a lot of false positives.

You may be better off creating a string range index on the attribute and doing value-match on that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please give me a sample of wildcards? I have tried wildcards but it is not working for me.